# Show console.log of NodeJs in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, console

I have a server `app.js` and multiple clients that can connect to my server. I display what the server say to the client in an `index.html` , but I want to do the same for the server when the client is talking to it, and **display what my client says to the server in an HTML page**. Right now I'm displaying it with `console.log()`

*Here's my code*, I'm using **Socket.io** : (I'm new to Javascript, this is just a test, so this is really simple )

**app.js / Server** :

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    // NEVER use a Sync function except at start-up!
    index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');

// Send index.html to all requests
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(index);
});

// Socket.io server listens to our app
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

// Send current time to all connected clients
function sendTime() {
    io.emit('clearance', { time: new Date().toJSON() });
}

// Send current time every 10 secs
setInterval(sendTime, 10000);

// Emit welcome message on connection
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Use socket to communicate with this particular client only, sending it it's own id
    socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });

    socket.on('i am client', console.log);
    socket.on('receiveClerance', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});



app.listen(3000);
```

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
            var data = "";
            socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
                addMessage(data.message);

                // Respond with a message including this clients' id sent from the server
                socket.emit('i am client', {data: 'foo!', id: data.id});
            });

            socket.on('clearance', function (data) {
                addMessage(data.time + data);
                $data = data;
            });

            socket.on('message', console.log.bind(console));

            function addMessage(message) {
                var text = document.createTextNode(message),
                    el = document.createElement('li'),
                    messages = document.getElementById('messages');

                el.appendChild(text);
                messages.appendChild(el);
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                btn.textContent = "Test";
                btn.onclick = function () {
                    socket.emit('receiveClerance', "La clerance " + $data + " est recu");
                }
                messages.appendChild(btn);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `console.log(data)` to a `socket.emit('message',data)`.

or make it a function that you can use everywhere, like :

```
function log(socket,data){
     console.log(data);
     socket.emit('message',data);
}
```

That way you'll still see the messages on your server console.

Comment: I thought about this silution, but I don't really want to make a special function for a client, I really want to separate my client from my server, and if I do this, I'm just creating a new type of client right ?

Comment: no you're not, you're just emitting messages to your client from the server, the same way you do : `socket.emit('welcome')` on connection. `emit` is the only way for your server to communicate with the client :) And you already have the handler on the client for the 'message' event, so it's a win-win

Comment: And how to display it on a special page ? Because i'm already running something on http://localhost:3000

Comment: the socket connection is bound to the page you open it on, so you can't do that. You could make a single page app, using angular or React and have "fake" urls like localhost:3000/#logs

Comment: This seem really complicated with my level :/ I guess there no simple way to do it then :(

Comment: nope, but you can use your current handler to console log on the client, or maybe display it in a hidden div with a button to toggle it on/off